# how to create regex for in c#

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to create a regular expression for following sample log file lines:

```
[user-agent info (Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25)]
[user-agent info (Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_1_3 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/26.0.1410.53 Mobile/10B329 Safari/8536.25)]
```

I want to match lines that begin with `[user-agent info` and ends with a square bracket.

I've tried `Regex regex = new Regex(@"[user-agent info\s*(^\s]+)");`, but this does not work. What did I get wrong, and how can I fix it?

Comment: @GazWinter well i am very new to the regex part and really does not progress much in this.Currently i am prgressing like this :Regex regex = new Regex(@"[user-agent info\s*(^\s]+)");

Comment: @user2364821 If you put it in the post (with the appropriate code tags!) you won't get this many downvotes.

Comment: currently i am trying to use the following regex Regex regex = new Regex(@"[user-agent info^]$)");

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like this:

```
Regex theExpression = new Regex(@"\[user-agent info.+\]")
```

What this does is:

1. First it matches a `[` character.
2. Then it matches `user-agent info`.
3. After that it matches any character but a new line, one or more times.
4. Finally it matches the closing brace.

(the `@` at the beginning of the string makes the string verbatim, i.e. literal. That's only so I don't have to put double backslashes, one for the Regex backslash, and one for the string one.